# PostgreSQL - Common autoincrement with inherited tables

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I'm currently trying the inheritance system with PostgreSQL but I have a problem with the auto-increment index in my child tables.

I have three tables: "Currency", "Crypto" and "Stable"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.currency
(
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    symbol VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.stable (id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY) INHERITS (public.currency);    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.crypto (id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY) INHERITS (public.currency);
```

I insered my data like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.stable (name, symbol) VALUES ('Euro', '€'), ('Dollar', '$'), ('Tether', 'USDT');    
INSERT INTO public.crypto (name, symbol) VALUES ('Bitcoin', 'BTC'), ('Ethereum', 'ETH'), ('Litcoin', 'LTC');
```

But this is my problem: I would like to have a unique identifier that increments itself through my parent table "Currency".
When I select, I have (take a look in my id: 1,2,3,1,2,3):

[image]

But, Is it possible to have something like this instead (1,2,3,4,5,6):

[image]

Is it a problem in my primary key?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to use [create sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) to set row numbers for sharing between multiple tables.

> define a new sequence generator

```
create sequence n_id;
```

Then we can use this `sequence` as below, sharing this `sequence` for those three tables.

```
create sequence n_id;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currency
(
    id INT default nextval('n_id') PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    symbol VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stable (id INT default nextval('n_id') PRIMARY KEY) INHERITS (currency);    
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS crypto (id INT default nextval('n_id') PRIMARY KEY) INHERITS (currency);
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4087a3d81098c849d7c53b8db48a6db6)

Comment: So cool thank you! But is it the only way? I mean, I have an other parent table with 4 childs. Do I need to create a sequence too? Or this is the only one way to "share" the auto increment

Comment: In my experience, create yourself `sequence` that shares the same increment id object for multiple tables